# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2.extras'

Tags: python, macos, psycopg2, apple-m1, odoo-15

I'm using Mac M1 and I'm having trouble opening ***Odoo***. I try to run the command **python3 odoo-bin --i base d db15 --limit-memory-hard 0** but it fails

````
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .convert import *
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 33, in <module>
    from odoo import SUPERUSER_ID, api
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1024, in <module>
    from odoo.modules.registry import Registry
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 21, in <module>
    from odoo.sql_db import TestCursor
  File "/Users/simjiahong/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 21, in <module>
    import psycopg2.extras
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2.extras'```
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the psycopg2 python module?
I haven't used M1 Mac (or any Mac recently), but in general (Linux/Windows/Android) you can install python modules using the pip or pip3 command (whichever exists on your system). Like this:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

or:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

You might need root access to do this, or use the --user option, like:

```
pip3 install --user psycopg2
```

Also, you can use a similar command if you use a virtual environment inside that (venv, anaconda, etc.).

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't work in my Mac M1.